# Food and non-food image on Clarifai API

Tags: clarifai

I want to classify food and non-food image by using Clarifai API.

It seems that the API is trying to assume that all images are food images, by default. For example, U pushed an image of people or animals to Clarifai and return back to us the results "water, beer..", etc with very high probability. Is there any way to overcome this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

‘Food’ model is able to analyze images and video around food (even down to the ingredient level)! It’s more speciifc and narrow, while ‘[General](https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/tag#general)’ model is used to analyze a more wide range of visual content.